# Problem about sequence of Riemann integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

a) Suppose that $g_n\ge0$ is a sequence of integrable function and  $\int_{a}^{b} g_n(x) dx$ converges to $0$. If $f$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g_n(x) dx$ converges to $0$.

b) If $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, then $\int_{0}^{1} x^nf(x) dx$ converges to $0$.

Attempt :

a) I use the fact that $0\le|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g_n(x) dx|\le\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|g_n(x) dx$. The right hand term goes to $0$ because of the hypothesis and the integrability of $f$ implies its boundedness. Any correction?

b) If I can prove that $\int_{a}^{b} x^n dx$ converges to $0$, I can use part a). But I'm not allowed to use the antiderivative method or the fundamental calculus theorem. How do I prove that? Using sums, what partition should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Part (a) is simply wrong...

Take $f(x)= x^{-1/2}$ and $g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} x^{-1/2}$. Then $\int_0^1 g_n(x)dx = \frac{2}{n} \to 0$. However, $f(x)g_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}x^{-1}$, so $\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x)=+\infty$ for all $n$.

You would need to assume that the sequence $fg_n$ is dominated by some integrable function, or something like that...

For part (b), you can just use the dominated convergence theorem, noting that $|x^nf(x)| \leq |f(x)|$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$, as well as the fact that $\lim_nx^nf(x) = 0$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: For part (a), is $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @BMS: Yes, it is Lebesgue integrable. And the (improper) Riemann integral exists as well. The precise value of the integral is $2$. (Strictly speaking, these functions are not defined at $0$, but we can define them arbitrarily there.)

Comment: Sorry, the context here distinguishes the improper one and here it must be the proper one. And haven't visited Lebesgue integral yet. This is a problem right after the discussion of proper Riemann integral. Here, it will state "improperly integrable" clearly if it means that. So how about it?

Comment: @BMS: Okay, then you should clarify that in the problem statement. Write "Riemann-integrable" instead of just "integrable." Sorry about the misleading answer.

Comment: OK then. How about it now? I also changed my answer finally knowing where I should use the nonnegativity.